# Extract subset data based on four conditions/coordinate ranges in R

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, conditional-statements

I have a long table (version1) from which I'd like to extract subset data based on four conditions in V16 and V17. They are defined as the range (coordinates) where I find the data. After extracting, I want to save the new subsets as separate groups or dataframes. All other columns should be kept inside that as well. However, I'm struggling with setting the conditions. This is what I got so far:

```
df_NA <- data.frame(version1) %>% 
  mutate(Groups = ifelse(V16>-85 & V16<30 & V17>25 & V17<75, 1, 0),
         Groups = cumsum(Groups)) %>%
group_split(Groups)
```

Is it possible to do this with ifelse?

Example data:

```
      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6       V7    V8    V9   V10   V11   V12   V13   V14   V15   V16   V17   V18 Groups
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>    <int> <dbl> <int> <int> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
 1    43     1     0    69    60     9 19501201  1080     0     1   641    30     0     0     0   136    29  3650      0
 2    43     1     1    69    60     9 19501201   884     0     1   705    30     3     0     0   136    29  3650      0
 3    43     1     2    70    61     9 19501201   553   293     1  1090    30     6     0     0   138    31  3650      0
 4    43     1     3    71    62     9 19501201   416   290     1  1240    30     9     0     0   140    33  3650      0
 5    43     1     4    72    63     9 19501201   396   287     1  1160    30    12     0     0   142    35  3650      0
 6    43     1     5    73    64     9 19501201   163   285     1  1440    30    15     0     0   144    37  3650      0
 7    43     1     6    74    66     9 19501201    29   475     1  1490    30    18     0     0   146    41  3650      0
 8    43     1     7    74    67     9 19501201  -257   222     1  1960    30    21     0     0   146    43  3650      0
 9    43     1     8    74    68     9 19501202  -216   222     1  1850    30     0     0     0   146    45  3650      0
10    43     1     9    74    69     9 19501202  -393   222     1  1950    30     3     0     0   146    47  3650      0
```

I'd like to keep all columns and rows which are inside the range of -85 and 30 (V16) as well as 25 and 75 (V17).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question! I expect all datasets that are within the above mentioned range as output.

Comment: your edit says `-85 and 30 (V16) as well as 25 and 75 (V17)`  Are these going to be separate datasets?

Comment: No, V16 has the latitudes and V17 the longitudes so the output should fulfill both the range of V16 and V17. One dataset in the end that's filtered according to these two ranges

Comment: if it  is `filter` then why you need `group_split` i.e. `version1 %>% filter(V16>-85 & V16<30 & V17>25 & V17<75)`

Comment: I use the group split to store every dataset separately since I also want to keep single groups of V3 that start with 0...9 until a next batch of 0...5 shows up in the data.

Comment: Based on the info provided, your expected output is not clear i.e. `'d like to keep all columns and rows which are inside the range of -85 and 30 (V16) as well as 25 and 75 (V17).`  This sounds more like a `filter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may need a `filter` here

```
library(dplyr)
version1 %>% 
      filter(between(V16, -85, 30), between(V17, 25, 75))
```

If we need to split based on the column 'V3'

```
version1 %>% 
      filter(between(V16, -85, 30), between(V17, 25, 75)) %>%
      group_split(group = cumsum(V3 == 0))
```

---

Or with `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(version1, V16>-85 & V16<30 & V17>25 & V17<75)
```

Comment: Thankyou! The filter in combination with the group_split was exactly what I needed.